ingress with KIND doesn't populate ADDRESS?
I am trying the code snippet from https://github.com/CKA-codespace/cks-crash-course/blob/master/exercises/02-tls-ingress/setup.yaml on a KIND cluster according to instructions in https://github.com/CKA-codespace/cks-crash-course/blob/master/exercises/02-tls-ingress/instructions.md
And, somehow, I can't get the ingress working?
$k -n t75 get pod --show-labels
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE     LABELS
nginx-deployment-d556bf558-ct8tm   1/1     Running   3 (72m ago)   5h49m   app=nginx,pod-template-hash=d556bf558
nginx-deployment-d556bf558-fjrkv   1/1     Running   3 (72m ago)   5h49m   app=nginx,pod-template-hash=d556bf558
nginx-deployment-d556bf558-l4wwg   1/1     Running   3 (72m ago)   5h49m   app=nginx,pod-template-hash=d556bf558

$k -n t75 get svc -o wide
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE     SELECTOR
accounting-service   ClusterIP   10.96.89.174   <none>        80/TCP    5h37m   app=nginx

$k create ing account-ingress \
--rule="accounting.internal.acme.com/*=accounting-service:80, tls=accounting-secret" \
--class=nginx  -n t75

$k -n t75 describe ing account-ingress
Name:             account-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        t75
Address:          
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
TLS:
  accounting-secret terminates accounting.internal.acme.com
Rules:
  Host                          Path  Backends
  ----                          ----  --------
  accounting.internal.acme.com  
                                /   accounting-service:80 (10.244.0.3:80,10.244.0.7:80,10.244.0.2:80)
Annotations:                    <none>
Events:                         <none>


why the address is not populated for the ingress?
$k get node -o wide
NAME               STATUS   ROLES           AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
c1-control-plane   Ready    control-plane   6d1h   v1.31.0   172.18.0.2    <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)   6.5.0-1025-azure   containerd://1.7.18

$cat /etc/hosts
172.18.0.2      accounting.internal.acme.com

$wget -O- https://172.18.0.2 --no-check-certificate
Connecting to 172.18.0.2 (172.18.0.2:443)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.18.0.2): Connection refused


Hi can you provide your yaml file for ingress?
